# Currency Format in IE11

Tags: javascript

I'm setting some totals in a jqGrid Footer row.  All is well in Chrome & Firefox but IE11 is causing me an issue.

The code is called in the loadComplete event of the grid but I think (!?) this is irrelevant.  I have isolated it to the the following lines

```
//works
$newFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_accountName]")
                                    .text("Grand Total:");
//No value (and stops the grid rendering properly (stops the toolbar appearing)
$newFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_orderValue]")
                                .text(currencyFormat(totalorderValue));
$newFooterRow.find(">td[aria-describedby=" + this.id + "_expenditure]")
                        .text(currencyFormat(totalExpenditureAmount));
```

If I remove the call to currencyFormat then the values appear (unformatted)

```
   function currencyFormat (value)
   {                
        var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
        //style: 'currency',
        style: 'decimal',
        //currency: 'GBP',
        minimumFractionDigits: 2,
        });

        return formatter.format(value);
    };
```

I've tested Chrome & Firefox and there is no issue.  IE11 is a problem.  Can anyone tell me why ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 only supports a subset of the Internationalisation API so you'll have to load a polyfill in order to support it. To make things even worse the versions of IE11 on Windows 7 and Windows 10 actually have different output creating even more fragmentation.

A couple of good resources for polyfilling this API:

- https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/
- https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/features/#Intl